# ASP.NET MVC4 Unity - Resolve dependencies on another project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have this configuration in my project MVC4 Unity and a generic configucion for drivers.

Bootstrapper.cs

```
namespace MyProyect.Web
{
    public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static void Initialise()
        {
            var container = BuildUnityContainer();
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(container));
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        }

        private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            container.RegisterType<MyProyect.Model.DataAccessContract.ICountryDao, MyProyect.DataAccess.CountryDao>();
            container.RegisterType<MyProyect.Model.DataAccessContract.IContactDao, MyProyect.DataAccess.ContactDao>();

            return container;
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...  
        Bootstrapper.Initialise();
        ...  
    }
```

GenericModelBinder.cs:

```
namespace MyProyect.Web.ModelBinder
{
    public class GenericModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder//, IValueProvider
    {
        protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
        {
            var resolver = (Unity.Mvc4.UnityDependencyResolver)DependencyResolver.Current;
            if (modelType == null)
            {
                return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, null);
            }

            return resolver.GetService(modelType);
        }
    }
}
```

Now that I need is to resolve a dependency in another project within the solution. My question is how I can do to that recognize the settings Unity in another project?. I currently I have this class but the current configuration does not bring in the MVC project.

```
namespace MyProyect.Model.ListData
{
    public abstract class ListDataGenericResolver
    {
        protected T ResolverType<T>()
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            UnityServiceLocator locator = new UnityServiceLocator(container);
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);

            //return unity.Resolve<T>();
            return (T)container.Resolve(typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

this is a example how to use `ListDataGenericResolver`:

```
namespace MyProyect.Model.ListData.Types
{
    public class CountryListData : ListDataGenericResolver, IGetListData
    {
        private readonly ICountryDao countryDao;
        private string defaultValue;

        public CountryListData(object defaultValue)
        {
            // Resolver
            this.countryDao = this.ResolverType<ICountryDao>();
            this.defaultValue = defaultValue == null ? string.Empty : defaultValue.ToString();
        }

        public IList<SelectData> GetData()
        {
            var data = this.countryDao.GetAllCountry(new Entity.Parameters.CountryGetAllParameters());
            return data.Select(d => new SelectData
                {
                    Value = d.CountryId.ToString(),
                    Text = d.Description,
                    Selected = this.defaultValue == d.CountryId.ToString()
                }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do this.

In Application_Start, I create the unity container. I have a custom library that I use for all of my MVC projects that I import through NuGet, so I make the call to its configure method, then call the other project's Configure() methods.  You could simply omit the custom library and add that code in here as well.  All of that keeps my Application_Start nice and clean.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Standard MVC setup
    // <removed>

    // Application configuration 
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    new CompanyName.Mvc.UnityBootstrap().Configure(container);
    new AppName.ProjectName1.UnityBootstrap().Configure(container);
    new AppName.ProjectName2.UnityBootstrap().Configure(container);

    // <removed>
}
```

This is the code for the custom MVC library's UnityBootstrap class

```
namespace CompanyName.Mvc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Bootstraps <see cref="CompanyName.Mvc"/> into a Unity container.
    /// </summary>
    public class UnityBootstrap : IUnityBootstrap
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public IUnityContainer Configure(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // Convenience registration for authentication
            container.RegisterType<IPrincipal>(new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.User));

            // Integrate MVC with Unity
            container.RegisterFilterProvider();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

            return container;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the other projects, I have a UnityBootstrap there, that was called from Application_Start:

ProjectName1:

```
namespace AppName.ProjectName1
{
    public class UnityBootstrap : IUnityBootstrap
    {
        public IUnityContainer Configure(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            return container.RegisterType<IDocumentRoutingConfiguration, DocumentRoutingConfiguration>();
        }
    }
}
```

ProjectName2: - and you can see in here, that this one depends on some other projects in another library and it is calling their Configure() methods to get them set up too...

```
namespace AppName.ProjectName2
{
    public class UnityBootstrap : IUnityBootstrap
    {
        public IUnityContainer Configure(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            new CompanyName.Security.UnityBootstrap().Configure(container);
            new CompanyName.Data.UnityBootstrap().Configure(container);

            container.RegisterSecureServices<AuthorizationRulesEngine>(typeof(UnityBootstrap).Assembly);

            return container
                .RegisterType<IAuthorizationRulesEngine, AuthorizationRulesEngine>()
                .RegisterType<IDateTimeFactory, DateTimeFactory>()
                .RegisterType<IDirectoryInfoFactory, DirectoryInfoFactory>()
                .RegisterType<IDirectoryWrapper, DirectoryWrapper>()
                .RegisterType<IEmailService, EmailService>()
                .RegisterType<IEntryPointService, EntryPointService>();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the IUnityBootstrap interface that is used throughout the code above (for your reference)

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines a standard interface for bootstrapping an assembly into a Unity container.
/// </summary>
public interface IUnityBootstrap
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers all of the assembly's classes to their public interfaces and performs any other necessary configuration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">The Unity container instance to configure.</param>
    /// <returns>The same IUnityContainer object that this method was called on.</returns>
    IUnityContainer Configure(IUnityContainer container);
}
```

I hope this helps you out.